# Mongoose: Update date of a document whenever document property is updated (changed)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Consider the following mongoose schema

```
new mongoose.Schema({
    lastUpdate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }, 
    ... other fields
}
```

In this case, the date will be set to whenever the document is created.

Now, if I update a document from this schema, as on now I manually add a 
`lastUpdate: new Date.now()` everywhere in my project.

Is there a way in mongoose, to update this field (lastUpdate) to current Date automatically on each update?

Comment: There's a plugin https://github.com/tarunc/mongoose-stamp

Comment: There is also ["timestamps"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) built into mongoose by default. No "plugin" required. `new Schema({ ... },{ timestamps: true })`. Adds a `createdAt` and `updateDated` at which get altered appropriately on updates.